# UITableView inside of UIScrollView cells can't be tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UITableView.

The cells within the tableview do not respond to taps. (i.e. - `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is never called).

The tableview doesn't not need to scroll.

If I move the UITableView out of the UIScrollView (so that it is a sibling instead of a child) then it works as it should.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is the tableView enabled? does it hit the other delegate methods? or does it even hit the data source methods?

Comment: Yes it does hit the delegate and data source methods. If you make it a sibling of the scrollview instead of a child then the method fires as it should.

Comment: have you set the cell alpha to zero by any chance?

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is that the content size of the scrollview is not tall enough. Increase the height of the scrollView content size

Comment: I saw somewhere that the developer docs say not to put items like web views or tables inside of a scrollview because of interaction problems. That said, I need to do it myself.  Did you figure this out?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find out what was going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the same thing once and it worked. Check the delegate of the table view to be set, not just the data source. Hope this helps.

Comment: The cells are not highlighted at all, or just the method doesn't get called? Any gesture recognizers added to the scroll view?

Comment: If you tap and hold then the cell becomes highlighted but the method is never called.

Comment: No gesture recognizers (other than the standard ones).